# How to write regular expression which accept numbers between 1 to 25000

Tags: regex

How to write regular expression which accept numbers between 1 to 25000>

I tried like this `^([1-2]?[1-4]?[0-9]{0,3}|25000)$`

Comment: You will get this and more at http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/

Comment: try this pattern          \b([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{2}|9[0-8][0-9]|99[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]{3}|9[0-8][0-9]{2}|99[0-8][0-9]|999[0-9]|1[0-9]{4}|2[0-4][0-9]{3}|25000)\b

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that will only accept a string with a number between 1 and 25000.
Without proceeding zero's.

```
^([1-9]\d{0,3}|1\d{4}|2[0-4]\d{3}|25000)$
```

It basically separates it in 4 ranges

```
[1-9]\d{0,3} : 1 to 9999  
1\d{4}       : 10000 to 19999  
2[0-4]\d{3}  : 20000 to 24999  
25000        : 25000
```

A regex101 test can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/ackN0Y/1)

To find those numbers as a part of a string, you could replace the start `^` and end `$` by a wordboundary `\b`.

*Btw, in most programming languages it's often simpler to just check if it's a number that's in the accepted range. Even in HTML there's an [input type](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_form_input_types.asp) for numbers where you can set the minimum and maximum.*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^(?!0$)((1\d|2[0-4]|\d)?\d{1,3}|25000)$
```

First negative lookahead will reject a value of only `0`.

The group `(1\d|2[1-4]|\d)?` means that a 5-digit number with an initial digit of `2` requires it to be followed by a `0-4`.

https://regex101.com/r/1DgbBM/4